# Infinite-dimensional analogue of "positive-negative splitting implies non-degeneracy"

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, differential-operators

(This question is related to [Splitting a space into positive and negative parts](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/7709/splitting-a-space-into-positive-and-negative-parts) but different.)

Given a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ over $\mathbb{R}$, what I call a "positive-negative splitting" for a symmetric bilinear form $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ on $V$ is a splitting $V=V_+\oplus V_-$ (not necessarily $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$-orthogonal) such that the restrictions of $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ to $V_+$ and $V_-$ are positive definite and negative definite, respectively.

If there exists such a splitting, then $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is written in matrix form as
$$
\langle x,y\rangle=
x^\mathsf{T}
\begin{pmatrix}
A_+&B\\
B^\mathsf{T}&A_-
\end{pmatrix}
y,
$$
where $A_+$ and $A_-$ are positive and negative definite symmetric matrices, respectively. We can calculate the determinant of the above block matrix by Gauss elimination and get
$$
\det
\begin{pmatrix}
A_+&B\\
B^\mathsf{T}&A_-
\end{pmatrix}=\det(A_+)\det(A_-\!-B^\mathsf{T}A_+^{-1}B)\neq0
$$
(note that $A_-\!-B^\mathsf{T}A_+^{-1}B$ is negative definite). So $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is non-degenerate in this case.

My question is:

**For a Hilbert space $(\mathcal{H},(\cdot|\cdot))$ and a bilinear form $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle:=(A\cdot|\cdot)$ on $\mathcal{H}$ given by a self-adjoint operator $A:\mathcal{H}\to\mathcal{H}$, does the existence of a positive-negative splitting still imply that $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is non-degenerate?**

Comment: Can't you just decompose $A=A_++A_-$ into positive and negative definite parts, using the spectral theorem (already in the finite-dimensional case)?

Comment: @Christian There is an off-diagonal part $B$ which I don't know how to handle unless $A_+$ or $A_-$ is assumed to be invertible. Could you give more details?

Comment: There is an orthogonal decomposition $V=V_+\oplus V_-$ such that $V_{\pm}$ are reducing for $A$, and the restrictions are positive/negative definite (use the spectral theorem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple proof:

Assume $\mathcal{H}=\mathcal{H}_+\oplus\mathcal{H}_-$, with $( A u| u)>0$ (resp. $<0$) for all nonzero $u\in\mathcal{H}_+$ (resp. $u\in\mathcal{H}_-$). We want to show $\ker A=0$. To this end, assume $Au=0$ and write $u=u_++u_-$ with $u_\pm\in\mathcal{H}_\pm$. If either $u_+$ or $u_-$ is zero, the assumption easily implies $u=0$. Otherwise, we have
$$
0=(Au|u_+)=(Au_+|u_+)+(Au_-|u_+)>(Au_-|u_+),
$$
$$
0=(Au|u_-)=(Au_+|u_-)+(Au_-|u_-)<(Au_+|u_-).
$$
In view of the self-adjointness, we get a contradiction.